GPU unavailable -Flutter (IOS)
I have successfully set up Firebase services in my Flutter app, and it functions as expected on Android OS. However, I am unsure why it is displaying a mysterious "GPU Unavailable" error on iOS.
I have been unable to resolve this issue for some time now.
Firebase stacktrace:
          Fatal Exception: FlutterError
0  ???                            0x0 FirebaseCrashlytics.recordError + 119 (firebase_crashlytics.dart:119)
1  ???                            0x0 FirebaseService.init.<fn> + 30 (firebase_service.dart:30)

Here is my implementation
class FirebaseService {
  static final FirebaseService _firebaseService = FirebaseService._();
  static FirebaseService get instance => _firebaseService;

  static FirebaseAnalytics? analytics;

  factory FirebaseService() {
    return _firebaseService;
  }

  static Future<void> init() async {
    if (!kDebugMode) {
      ///  Firebase analytics
      analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
      await analytics?.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
      await analytics?.logAppOpen();

      /// Firebase crashlytics
      FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
      };

      // Pass all uncaught asynchronous errors that aren't handled by the Flutter framework to Crashlytics
      PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
        return true;
      };
    }
  }

  FirebaseService._();
}


I attempted to search on Google but did not find any comprehensive resource addressing this issue effectively.
